# How are the Jyothirlingas formed in 12 places of India?

Tags: jyotirlinga

What is the reason why these Jyothirlingas have formed on the earth?
What is the story behind these 12 Jyothirlingas?
How many of these are Svayambhu Jyothirlingas?

Comment: Stories of all jyotirlingas are already mentioned on this site.

Comment: -1 for no research effort. Try searching within the site before you post a question.